# Turning list of 2D tensors with different length to one 3D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a list of 3 tensors with the shape: `(8, 2), (8, 4), (8, 6)`

And I want to turn this list into this shape: `(8, 3, x)`

How do I do this? I know I need to use some combination of `torch.cat`, `torch.stack` and `torch.transpose`, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need to use `torch.cat`, but also `torch.reshape`. Assume the following:

```
a = torch.rand(8,2)
b = torch.rand(8,4)
c = torch.rand(8,6)
```

And assume that it is indeed possible to reshape the tensors to a `(8,3,-1)` shape, where `-1` stands for as long as it need to be, then:

```
d = torch.cat((a,b,c), dim=1)
e = torch.reshape(d, (8,3,-1))
```

I'll explain. Because the 1st dimension if different in `a,b,c` the concatenation has to be along the 1st dimension, as seen in variable `d`. Then, you can reshape the tensor as seen in `e` where the `-1` stands for "as long as it needs to be".

Comment: Completely forgot that -1 existed for this, thank you!
found out I actually can't reshape it to what I wanted, but figured that my model might not work properly

Comment: Sure, if you have more problems with your model I'll be happy to try and help